# How to start TDD in Django?

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd

I'm new both to Django and unit testing but since I'm starting a project after a fair amount of time playing with the framework I decided to give unit testing a shot.

My enthusiasm aside, I am pretty lost as to how to plan the developing process. I did a little search in github for Django projects that use unit testing and I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/oscarcp/e-cidadania/tree/446e87e553a635db340729ee164b4a89e5598c60). I see there are only tests on the "tagging" app, and it looks good but I have no idea how to break it down. Why the "models.py" file in the apps/tagging/tests/? The model classes there have nothing to do with the ones in apps/tagging/models.py ...

Any ideas on how to figure this out or find a good example on how to implement unit testing into a django environment ?

Also, I read in the docs that Django introduced unittest2 in 1.3 so would "Django 1.1 Testing And Debugging - by Karen M. Tracey" be a helpful reading or do you think it could cause some confusion?

Anyways, I appreciate any input in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I may plug my own tutorial, it covers how to do TDD in Django from the ground up. I cover the same steps as the "official" Django tutorial, except using TDD every step of the way.  That includes full browser-automation testing with Selenium (which allows you to test behaviour from the end-user's point of view, including the possibility of including javascript later). I also show how to use the Django TestClient for unit testing...

http://tdd-django-tutorial.com

Comment: I think I stumbled upon this project (the django poll app + all the tests) in github sme time ago. I didn't know there was a step by step of it too... Thanks mate. It's been a while but I'll have a look at it.

Comment: see how you get on!  I've tried to write it so it assumes no knowledge whatsover, and really goes step-by-step... Comments much appreciated!

Comment: I'm reading it right now... didn't even know functional tests could be automated. I had heard of Selenium but I never read what the fuzz was all about. Looks great so far. I do have a question though.... how often do you commit your code while unit testing? I'm going through the Poll model creation bit,... and it would seem a bit of over doing it if I were to write the test, run it, add a field, commit, run the test, add another field, commit, run the test, etc... what's the pace for committing your code changes?

Comment: good question... I was wondering whether I should address VCS at some point. My pattern tends to be: first draft of FT gets a commit. Then, you could do separate commits for each unit test and its associated code changes, but that's probably excessive.  I'd say, for example when creating a new model, write the unit tests, get them all passing, and then commit the tests and the working model class together... the idea is to make your commits granular enough that it's easy to revert changes later...

Comment: OK I understand. If I had something more complex then I should commit more often and so on. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think it's good to commit after each each of the smallest coherent, self-consistent working change. For example, change the FT, add a new unit test, change a few lines of product code, then commit. All tests should pass when you commit, always. Sometimes a commit is just a refactor of product code, with no test changes. Sometimes commits are just a few lines - maybe only one. Separate your 'implementing new functionality' commits from your 'behaviour-preserving refactoring' commits. Separate out your 'whitespace & comments' commits.

Answer (score 2):

Django does a great job of getting you started.  They outline what should and shouldn't be tested, and how to use some of their built in test classes.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/

In addition i'd recommend `django-nose` test runner.  It has a lot of great plugins.

I think general convention is to have a tests.py file in each app.

I personally will write at least 1 test for each function that I create.  More depending on how complicated logic is.  As the app develops these tests develop into regression tests for my project.

Comment: Do you have or know of any good example projects so I could check the tests for the different application parts (forms, views, urls, models, sessions, etc)? That would be really helpful. Also, what's the point of django-nose? what kind of plugins do you use with it?